# Running Buildozer from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: bash, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've made the decision to enter the world of mobile app development. I've gotten pretty familiar with Kivy in order to do this. I'm running into wall after wall trying to deploy anything I make.

First off, I am absolutely unable to create a working VM on my machine at home. I attempted to Enable virtualization in my machine's BIOS so I could use the 64-bit version of Ubuntu, and I can't find the option in the menus. The 32-bit option throws a fatal "kernel panic" error at installation.

I installed the new Bash on Ubuntu on Windows utility in an attempt to use that to run the Buildozer tool to package my .apk file. However, Buildozer cannot be run as root. I get a security issue when trying to access the app directory (which lives on my Windows host's home drive) as a non-root user. On top of that, I've tried to move the files into the lxss folder, where the Ubuntu files seem to live.

I'm running out of options entirely. My entire process is being stymied because of this one tool simply not cooperating. What can I do to get Buildozer to run properly knowing that I'm almost exclusively limited to a Windows machine?

Edit: The VM image at https://kivy.org/#download will not run for me either. It gets hung up while booting.

Comment: You do not need to disable WSL for Virtualization to run.  They are completely orthogonal systems. Moreover, you do not need to run buildozer as root.  I can't tell you if it is working or not, but you can install WSL and run it as an unprivileged (albeit sudoer) user.

If you try to run it as an unprivileged user, and it still doesn't work, please post an issue on the BashOnWindows issues github page.

Comment: I have posted this issue to the GitHub page as you suggested. Running Buildozer as a sudoer yields the same result as running as root i.e. Buildozer hangs after about 6 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start off with, the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is not a full-fledged Linux distribution. A lot of things do not work on it, and unless you are testing software or doing very simple stuff, it is best to leave it disabled.

Next, to run virtualization on your machine, you most likely have to disable WSL and reboot your machine.

To enable hardware virtualization (a requirement for 64bit guests), you have to enable it in your BIOS. This is labeled as VT-x or AMD-V depending on your processor type. Enable this, save the BIOS configuration and then restart the machine.

Next, download virtualbox from virtualbox.org and install it; make sure you check for updates as well. Reboot the machine, because virtualbox installs some networking drivers.

Next, [download the virtualbox image for kivy](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B112pXITp0hJU3dJb25hbWJ3RHM&authuser=0) this is just a hard drive image, you still have to configure it. Download it, and extract the archive.

Next, open the virtualbox manager on your computer and create a new virtual machine. Select "linux" and "Ubuntu 64bit".

Next, under the Hard Drive section, select "use existing drive", and select the .vdi file from the archive you downloaded.

Next, go to Setting and increase the video RAM to more than 32MB and enable 3D acceleration.

Finally, start the virtual machine.

Once the machine boots, there should be a readme file on the desktop which has further instructions.

Comment: I booted into BIOS already. I looked in every conceivable location for anything that looked like it might relate to virtualization, but to no avail. What exactly is WSL?

Comment: I re-read your Answer, no need to answer my previous question.

I ended up re-installing the VM image, and for one reason or another, it works now. I'm marking your answer as accepted since it may prove helpful for someone else with the same issue.